# I'm looking for a way to get Google Analytics to recognize clicks that lead to external site

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to create a goal in my analytics page. The goal is "when a user clicks a certain link", the problem is the link is an external link with different domain than my website so i cant just write `/pagename` in the goal details.

I've researched and tried different things, but examples I've seen only shows how it works when its an internal page. I don't have access to the website back end code, just its Google Ads and Analytics account.

In the analytics menu, I set my goal description as "when user clicks x button" Goal type is "Destination".

And then under goal details, I tried regular expression like this:

```
.*externalsite*html$
```

I also tried

```
^http://externalsite\.com/
```

and

```
/^http:\/\/externalsite\.com
```

and some other regex that I forgot.

Google kept saying the goal would have 0 conversion results, which isn't true as I've received email about the thing this click event was about just about everyday.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is, that Google Analytics by default is not tracking clicks on external links on your site, only visits to your own pages. Although it is not explicitly stated in your post, I assume, that you don't have tracking of external links implemented in any custom ways. If this is the case, you will need to get your Analytics tracking improved, either by accessing the site code via a developer, or by getting Google Tag Manager implemented also by a developer, which will make similar task very easy. Newertheless, I'd recommend implementing external link tracking with events, as using additional pageviews for this, as it would have major impact on your pageview based metrics, like bounce rate and average pages per session metrics

In case you have implemented external link tracking as pageviews, you need to make the following adjustments.

By default, all these page visits get tracked and displayed in the [pagePath dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) by their path, and domain is tracked separately in [hostname dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_hostname). Goal setting will only consider pagepath, so you need to set up an Advanced view filter, to modify pagePath dimension, and include hostname in it. Your filter would look something like this:
[image]

This would allow you to use a Regular Expression in your destination type goal, and filter for the domain as well. However, protocoll will still not be included, so something like this could work, which simply checks for the third party domain:

```
example\.com\/
```